# Python Discord Bot that bans people on a list

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I made a bot that bans people on a list. The list is the users' ids. The first part that messages them works but the second part that bans them doesn't work.

```
if message.content.startswith('purge') and message.author.id == "317026781708288024":
    logID()
    msg = "Hey something bad happened and you got banned good luck the server is down now"
    f = open("ID.log","r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        member = await client.get_user_info(line)
        try:
            await client.send_message(member, msg)
        except Exception: 
            pass
        await client.ban(member, delete_message_days=7)
    f.close()
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/jacob/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 307, in _run_event
yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
File "Evster.py", line 141, in on_message
await client.ban(member, delete_message_days=7)
File "/home/jacob/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 1735, in ban
yield from self.http.ban(member.id, member.server.id, delete_message_days)
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'server'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`discord.py` uses two different classes to represent an account, `User` and `Member`.  `Member` is a subclass of `User`.  A `User` object represents a discord account (you, me, a bot), while a `Member` object represents the state of an account on a particular server and includes nicknames, roles, permissions, etc.

You can't ban a `User` because `User` objects don't contain any information about the server they are to be banned from.  Instead, you need to get the member object of that server.  Fortunately, `Server` objects have a method that makes that easy

```
member = message.channel.server.get_member(line)
```

Comment: I used your code but now I get this error:
`Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jacob/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "Evster.py", line 141, in on_message
    await client.ban(member, delete_message_days=7)
  File "/home/jacob/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 1735, in ban
    yield from self.http.ban(member.id, member.server.id, delete_message_days)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'`

Comment: That's your bot telling you that there is no member with that id on that server. You may want to try passing `line.rstrip()` instead, there could be a line break in that string that's messing things up